# Riemann Integrable and Uniform Convergence

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

> Prove that if $f_n \to f_0$ uniformly on $[a,b]$, and all of these functions are Riemann integrable, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} \int_a^b f_n(x) \, dx = \int_a^x f_0(x) \, dx.$

I would try to say since we have uniform convergence we know,

$\lim_{\ n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n{(x)}=\int_{a}^{b}f_0{(x)}\ dx$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n{(x)}-\int_{a}^{b}f_0{(x)}\ dx=0$

$\Rightarrow \lim_{\ n\to\infty}\int_{a}^{b}f_n{(x)}-f_0{(x)}\ dx=0$

$\Rightarrow \int_{a}^{b}[\lim_{\ n\to\infty}(f_n(x)-f_0(x))]=0$ ($\textbf{unif convg})$.

Morso, $\sup|(f_n-f_0)|<\epsilon$

Here, the integrand is "$\textbf{0}$" since by assumption $f_n\to f_0$.

I'm not sure about this.

Comment: Hint: If $f_n \to f_0$ uniformly, for all $\epsilon$ there is $N$ such that $|f_n(x) - f_0(x)|<\epsilon$ for all $x$ and $n\geq N$.

Comment: So we can use this to say that this integral $\int_{a}^{b}(f_n(x)-f_0(x)) dx < \epsilon(b-a)$.

Comment: The key here is that if $f,g$ are integrable and $f(x) \le g(x)$, then $\int_a^b f(x) dx \le \int_a^b g(x) dx$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $N$ such that if $n \ge N$, then $|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le { \epsilon \over b-a}$ for all $x \in [a,b]$.

Then $\int_a^b |f(x)-f_n(x)| dx \le \int_a^b { \epsilon \over b-a} dx = \epsilon$.
Hence $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_a^b |f(x)-f_n(x)| dx = 0$.

Since $|\int_a^b (f(x)-f_n(x))dx | \le \int_a^b |f(x)-f_n(x)| dx$, and
$\int_a^b (f(x)-f_n(x))dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx - \int_a^b f_n(x) dx$, we see that 
$\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_a^b  f_n(x) dx = \int_a^b f(x)dx$.

Comment: I feel so stupid. Your hint in the comment, should of lead me to this.

Comment: You are missing this step $$\int_a^b |f(x)-f_n(x)|dx  \leq \int_a^b \sup_{a\leq x \leq b} |f(x)-f_n(x)| dx. $$

Comment: Well the sup of that is $<\epsilon$ since we have uniform convergence, so is this needed? But I know it would go right after the inequality on the second line.

Comment: It is a crucial step.

Comment: Well, the $\sup$ is not really crucial. The fact is that if $a(x) \le b(x)$ then $\int a \le \int b$. That is the crucial fact and that is what is used with $a(x) = |f(x)-f_n(x)|$ and $b(x) = {\epsilon \over b-a}$.

Comment: @copper.hat: You are given the uniform convergence and its defined as $\sup_{a\leq x\leq b}|f_n(x)-f(x)|<\epsilon$.

Comment: That is true, but what I wrote above is still true. For some $N$, if $n \ge N$, then $|f(x)-f_n(x)| \le \epsilon$ for all $x$.

Comment: @copper.hat used an alternative and equivalent definition of uniform convergence.

Comment: How can you say $f-f_n$ is integrable?

Comment: @IvinBabu The sum (or difference) of two Riemann integrable functions is integrable.

Answer (score 5):

I think it fits here: If $(f_n)$ is a sequence of Riemann-integrable functions on $[a,b]$ with $f_n \rightrightarrows f$, then $f$ is also Riemann-integrable on $[a,b]$.

Let $\varepsilon > 0$ be given. Then from the uniform convergence, we have that (for big enough $n$)
$$-\frac{\varepsilon}{3(b-a)} +f_n< f < \frac{\varepsilon}{3(b-a)}+f_n$$
Which means that
$$\underline{\int}\left(-\frac{\varepsilon}{3(b-a)} +f_n\right)\leqslant \underline{\int} f \leqslant \overline{\int} f \leqslant \overline{\int} \left(\frac{\varepsilon}{3(b-a)}+f_n\right)$$
Which means that
$$\int f_n -\frac{\varepsilon}{3} \leqslant \underline{\int} f \leqslant \overline{\int} f \leqslant \int f_n + \frac{\varepsilon}{3}$$
I.e.
$$\left|\overline{\int} f -\underline{\int} f\right| \leqslant \left|\overline{\int}f -\int f_n\right|+\left|\underline{\int} f-\int f_n \right|\leqslant \frac{\varepsilon}{3}+\frac{\varepsilon}{3} < \varepsilon$$
Which means that
$$\underline{\int} f = \overline{\int} f$$
So $f$ is Riemann-integrable.